# How to authenticate with Azure Resource Manager using managed identity in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to use the managedIdentity to get a token that I can then use to list resources in the resource group. I am getting an error when attempting to get the token. The GetToken() api seems to be adding other strings (offline_access openid) internally to the scope I provided and fails that the scope is not a valid url. From the error, it appears that I am not using the api correctly. But I am also following the documentation. Could some one please help track down what the issue is in my code.

Code:

```
var managedIdentityCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = managedIdentityId });
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider("RunAs=App");
AccessToken accessToken = managedIdentityCredential.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/" }));
```

Error:
Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed. ---> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://management.azure.com/ offline_access openid profile is not valid. The scope format is invalid. Scope must be in a valid URI form https://example/scope or a valid Guid <guid/scope>.

Answer (score 0):

To get the token with MSI(managed identity), make sure you ran the code in the [Azure services that support the managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-services-that-support-managed-identities-for-azure-resources).

After enabling the system-assigned MSI for the service, then use the code below directly.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider("RunAs=App");
string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/").Result;
Console.WriteLine(accessToken)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @joywang.

When I ran your code, I get an exception: AzureServiceTokenProviderException with the message "Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. An error occurred while sending the request.". This error is understandable since the account that is executing the code is not the managed identity itself but the AD app that was granted access control (IAM) access to the "Managed Application Operator Role" role on the Managed Identity. The Managed Identity in turn has reader access on the resource group which I wish to access.

Comment: Maybe the token is the wrong thing to get. Here is an example to access a key vault:

`
var mICredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = managedIdentityId });
new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVault.VaultUri), mICredential);
`

In a similar fashion, how do I come up with an example to list the resources in a resource group that the managed identity has access to?

Comment: In this case, I am running locally via an emulator to test out Geneva actions (which works by executing as an AD app that we have to grant role access to my Azure resources like key vaults and azure resource groups).

Comment: @SharathMalladi If you run the code locally, why you need to use MSI? MSI will not work locally, I have mentioned that in the first line in my reply. If you want to run the code to get the token locally, you could use the VS auth or a service principal to auth directly, e.g. if you use a service principal, modify the code with `var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider("RunAs=App;AppId={AppId};TenantId={TenantId};AppKey={ClientSecret}");` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support

Comment: Yes. If a managed identity credential has permissions on a resource group and I grant access on a managed identity credential to an AD app via access control, how does the AD app use that to perform operations on the resource group? Is that even possible?

I was able to do the same for reading secrets from a key vault. How do I repeat this for doing azure resource operations?

Comment: @SharathMalladi Of course you can, just get the token and use the token to call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/), or you can use the new sdk depends on the specific resource you want.